# Hosting Azure Database Locally

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, azure

I'm trying to host an Azure database on my local machine and access it from another machine on the same network.

Is there any solutions to achieve this, or alternative methods to hosting a database on the local network like SQL Server 2012 does?

Ideally I would like to implement Azure in the way that a SQL Server works with the connection string referencing the server (my local host in this case).

I'm currently working in Visual Studio 2012, I downloaded the Azure SDK and created a Azure database.  From this point on I'm stuck.

Comment: What do you mean with: "host an Azure database"? There is no emulation for Azure SQL. Maybe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106433/is-there-a-local-emulator-for-sql-azure

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a means to test my application making use of Azure, but without actually using the Azure Services hosted online (and requiring a license)

Comment: by "created an Azure database", do you mean created a SQL Database within the Azure portal?  If so, then no, you can't really test that thoroughly locally since there are features of SQL Database not supported in on-premises SQL Server.  Testing SQL Database in Azure though doesn't require a license, just a subscription, which you can get free as well (http://aka.ms/GetAzureTrial.  If you're setting up a VM inside of Azure on which you've installed SQL Server then you should be able to host that same VM locally and test there - keeping in mind that dynamics of latency, networking, etc. differ