# Creating a SQL Server Database on the local Azure emulator (Not online)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure-sql-database

I have succeeded in creating a basic tables running on the azure emulator in Visual Studio 2012 and I have also managed to create a couple of SQL Server databases that work with applications on a single computer. I was wondering how you would combine these to create a SQL Server database running on my local azure emulator ,that allows other computers and mobile devices to connect to it.

I have done a bit of research on this and there are quite a few topics about it, but it seems like you have to create the database on the Azure online portal and then connect to it, but I was hoping to skip this since I want to avoid connecting to any online resources.

If someone could just please point me in the right direction , because I'm still pretty unsure about using azure and all it's features. It would be great if I could create a SQL Server database on visual studio and then just specify a connection string to it through azure. (Must connect through Azure)

"For local testing, you can use a local SQL Server (full, express or even CE) within your app - just use local connection string's in place of the SQL Azure ones in your .cscfg or .config files - then the local compute instance will connect just like any other local process would." Quoted from [How do I test locally against SQL Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106433/is-there-a-local-emulator-for-sql-azure)

I have read that question post, but the answer was a bit too vague for rooky programming knowledge.
I think it might be able to help me if someone could also maybe elaborate on it.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

there is no emulator for Azure SQL Database.

As the post you referenced pointed out, you use a local SQL instance (CE, server, express, localdb) to simulate your database operations.

when you're ready to move to Azure SQL Database, you just change your connection string to point to your Azure SQL Database instead of your local database.

please take note though that Azure SQL Database and your typical SQL installation have feature differences, so that into account. you may be able to run some T/SQL on your local instance that is not supported in Azure SQL